# What are the hardware and software settings of the virtual machine used in Travis CI?

Tags: virtual-machine, travis-ci

The [TravisCI tutorial](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/tutorial/) says,

> In order to run builds, Travis CI’s system clones a repository, from
> which the build is triggered, to the build environment. The build
> environment is an isolated virtual machine or an LXD container, which
> gets terminated as soon as the build finishes

Question: What are the hardware and software settings in the "isolated virtual machine" Travis CI uses, e.g. memory size, CPU frequency, etc? I would like to know about the settings because I am testing a piece of software using a third-party dynamic analysis tool, similar to Valgrind,  that is quite memory-consuming, and the quality of the testing process somehow relates to how much memory is being offered in the testing environment.

Comment: That's up to the Travis maintainers, and will change over time. What *problem* are you trying to solve that's led you to look at the VM settings?

Comment: Thanks. I would like to know about the settings because I am testing a piece of software using a third-party dynamic analysis tool, similar to Valgrind, that is quite memory-consuming, and the quality of the testing process somehow relates to how much memory is being offered in the testing environment.

Comment: Did you look in the docs: https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/reference/overview/